# Does the Linux Kernel use event-loops to keep itself alive?

Tags: linux, kernel, linux-kernel, kernel-modules

I am just wondering what mechanism does the Linux Kernel program use to keep itself alive.
Any normal C program will terminate by executing its statements sequentially.
If we wanted to keep that program running we use an infinite loop [event loop].

Does the Linux kernel too employ this mechanism, or are there other ways that it uses to keep itself alive?

Comment: Hello! I think [this thread](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/426190/why-is-cpu-idle-called-as-the-last-function-of-the-start-kernel-routine) may answer your question.

Comment: @undercat yup that's what I wanted.